# How can I recover data from .incomplete and .previous Time Machine backups?

Tags: macos, time-machine, data-recovery, sparsebundle, file-recovery

I’m helping someone who has deleted their Time Machine backup by accident. All that is contained within the sparsebundle are .incomplete and .previous folders. I would like to recover as much data as possible so I need a way to combine all the changes from each folder essentially.

Also I may first attempt to recover the deleted files with software, does anyone have preferences between R-Studio, UFS, or another software? And would scanning for deleted files work the same within a sparsebundle?

Thanks!